# pip3 install Pipenv warnings

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip, virtualenv

I ran the following command in my terminal( I am operating on MacOs Catalina):

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

I received the final log

```
WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/Users/rubenolmos/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script virtualenv is installed in '/Users/rubenolmos/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/rubenolmos/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2020.6.20 distlib-0.3.1 filelock-3.0.12 importlib-metadata-1.7.0 pipenv-2020.8.13 virtualenv-20.0.31 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4 zipp-3.1.0
```

This is my first Mac. I have a couple of questions: I was not able to run the command using pip, and only was able to use pip3 to run it. Is it bad that I ran it in this format. when I try to run the command:

```
python3 -m pip3 install pipenv
```

I get an error that the module pip3 is not recognized, however when I run the following:

```
python3 -m pip install pipenv
```

I get the follow output

```
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (2020.8.13)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv) (20.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (3.1.0)
```

First I would like to understand exactly what the warning is and more importantly why it is occurring. I have a feeling that it has to do with the pip that was used or the way int which the command was run.

Secondly, I am curious as to why the pip doesn't work without the use of python3, why the pip3 works without the use of python3 but fails when it is used with python3. I understand that it probably has to do with the way that my system is configured, but I am trying how to best configure my system to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip3 is the python 3 version, pip is for python2.7(which is no longer available). Your warnings are from your path being not matching. https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac will help explain it better.

try:
get_pip.py

Since python 3 is install, correct? Try cd to the directory where you python 3 is saved, and run get_pip.py. Then run the file with python3 get_pip.py. This should get pip3 installed on your machine.

Also I had trouble getting it on my Mac for the first time, but the above worked fine for me.

Comment: yes python3 is installed I have python, python2 and python3 installed. I think that I am just going to go ahead and try to install home-brew first. Then run the python environment, if this doesn't work then Ill add it to the PATH manually. Then installl pip3

Comment: home-brew is highly recommended if you haven't used it before.

Comment: Yes I have used it before, I solved the issue using home-brew and updating to pip3.